# SQL : query to retrieve data

Tags: sql, count, max

I'm working on a SQL project where i have the tables Actor AlbumId TrackId InvoiceLine and Invoice and i want to retrieve the names of the actors whose tracks are the top 3 sold.

ex(from a table of 10 artists )  .

Drake (300 tracks sold )

Kendrick (233 tracks)

Cardi B (200 tracks)

I'm new to SQL and i have my diagram below . I know that i have to connect the tables of actor album track and invoice to get the 3 max(count(trackid)) from the invoiceline table to give me the names of the actors that have made the specific tracks

Thank you for your time 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below joins the relevant tables together and uses the aggregrate `COUNT` function to count the number of invoice lines associated with a song.

You may want to use TOP 3 WITH TIES in case there are two artists in third place with same number of sales

```
SELECT  TOP 3
        ar.Name
FROM    InvoiceLine il
        JOIN Track t
            ON il.TrackId = t.TrackId 
        JOIN Album al
            ON al.AlbumId = t.AlbumId
        JOIN Artist ar
            ON ar.ArtistId = al.ArtistId
GROUP BY ar.Name
ORDER BY COUNT(t.TrackId) DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for the top 3 tracks sold then this will give you the top 3 trackids. Then join this to your Track, Album and Artist tables to get the artist.

```
SELECT TOP 3 trackid 
FROM InvoiceLine
GROUP BY trackid
ORDER BY COUNT(trackid) DESC
```

Comment: "i want to retrieve the names of the actors whose tracks are the top 3 sold."